# Error 404 when trying to download Image from Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I got a button to upload i picture. It will create a folder on the root with the name of the userID. In there there will be the picture. Everything works great. So now i want to download the picture in the oncreate method that the user sees his picture while going on his profile! But it dont work it always gives me the 404 error. Does someone know how i can call the file to download?

Upload:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String userID = i.getStringExtra("UID");

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Lädt hoch...");
            mProgressDialog.show();

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            StorageReference childref = mStorage.child(userID).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

            childref.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Picasso.with(Profil.this).load(downloadUri).fit().centerCrop().into(mImageView);
                    Toast.makeText(Profil.this, "Hochladen Erfolgreich!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
}
```

Download:

```
mStorage.child("2CZ4ak9TgFSNeHACowSEc5QiUBG3/28881.jpeg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Toast.makeText(Profil.this, "Download Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Toast.makeText(Profil.this, "Download failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Error Message:

```
09-16 15:52:21.909 30538-31025/highelo.drivetogether E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                                         Object does not exist at location.
                                                                          Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
09-16 15:52:21.909 30538-31025/highelo.drivetogether E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
                                                                         java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
                                                                             at bzr.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:424)
                                                                             at bzr.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:1404)
                                                                             at bzl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:53)
                                                                             at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamg$zza$zza.zztj(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzamj.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzama.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzama.zzd(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.storage.zzb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```